# Share user token stored as localstorage between web application and chrome extension developed using ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a web application and chrome extension developed using ReactJs. I'm storing user token to my localstorage, how can I access this token inside the chrome extension.

Thanks in Advance
Tibin Mathew

Comment: Do it in your content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm,  I haven't used the content script before with chrome extension. Could you please give me a use case example.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).